# Proving $W$ is a subspace of $P_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, polynomials

Let $V = P_{2}$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$ with real coefficients, and let $W$ be the subset of polynomials $p(x)$ in $P_{2}$ such that:

$$\int_{-2}^{0}p(x)\,dx = 4\int_{0}^{2}p(x)\,dx.$$

$b)$ Find a basis for $W$, and compute $\dim(W)$.

For $b)$, I know after plugging in an example p(x)=a and p(x)=a+bx+c^2 I get that a = 0, where do I go from here?

Comment: Hinty stuff:  If $p(x)$ is  in $P_2$ the it satisfies the integral equality;  you need to show that $\alpha p(x)$ also satisfies the integral equality, where $\alpha$ is a scalar.  Then you need to show closure under addition, so let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ satisfy the integral equality, and show that $(p+q)(x)$ also satisfies it.

Comment: @B.Goddard for the scalar multiple, does it suffice to say that by properties of integrals I can pull out the scalar "a" so (a)(integral from -2 to 0) = (4a) (integral from 0 to 2) and then divide by "a" on both sides?

Comment: Yes.  You're on your way....

Comment: @B.Goddard and for the addition, can I just split up the integral over (p + q)(x) dx into the integral over p(x) + the integral over q(x)?

Comment: Almost too easy, eh?

Comment: @B.Goddard but on the right side, will I start with = (4) the integral over (p + q)(x)dx, then when I split it up will I have (4) integral p(x)dx + (4) integral q(x)dx? does the 4 go to both?

Comment: Distributive property of multiplication over addition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for (a) you should probably use the fact that the integral is a linear form over $V$. (This fact is not difficult to prove, but you should perhaps write it down.)

Before going on (b), you should try a few examples. Such as $a, aX,aX^2, aX+bX^2$, (with $a,b\in \mathbb R$) just to see what's happening.

For example,

$$ \int_{-2}^0 aX \, dX= \frac a2 \big[X^2\big]^0_{-2} = \frac a2 (-(-2)^2) = -2a $$

and

$$ \int_0^2 aX \, dX = \frac a2 \big[X^2\big]^2_0 = 2a$$

so in order to have $2a \times 4 = -2a$ you get $a=0$.

Comment: I’m not so sure that looking at monomials will be all that enlightening. Doing so will tell you is that they’re not elements of $W$, which doesn’t really get you any closer to finding a basis for it.

Comment: But it helps to get closer to the problem and manipulate a bit the integration of polynomials. That's why I said "before going on (b)".

Comment: So when I plug in a+bx+cx^2 into both I get the linear equation 6a+10b+8c=0. How do I write a basis of this in polynomials? I know that if this was a matrix I could write {(-5/3,1,0),(-4/3,0,1)} where b and c are free, but how do I write a basis of polynomials? And I think that that dimension of W is 2 because there are two free variables?

Comment: @John $(a,b,c)=\lambda(-5/3,1,0)+\mu(-4/3,0,1)$, but $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the coefficients of the polynomial $a+bx+cx^2$ so...

Comment: @amd So I wrote the basis of W as the set of two polynomials {(-5/3+x),(-4/3+x^2)}. Is that the right way?

Comment: @John Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, linearity of definite integrals should give you what you need to solve the first part.

For the second, I suggest starting by plugging in a generic element of $V$ into the defining equation of the subspace, i.e., expand $$\int_{-2}^0a+bx+cx^2\,dx=4\int_0^2a+bx+cx^2\,dx.$$ This will give you, after a bit of manipulation, a homogeneous linear equation in the coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$. If you treat the tuple $(a,b,c)$ as an element of $\mathbb R^3$, you can then use methods that you already know to find the dimension of the space and find a basis for it.