# Finding a basis over P2

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Let $V=P_2$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$
 with real coefficients, and let $W$
 be the subset of polynomials $p(x)$
 in $P_2$ such that:

$$\int_{-2}^0 p(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 4 \cdot \int_0^2 p(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

B) Find a basis for $W$, and compute $\dim(W)$.

Doing an example with just $a$ or $a+bx+cx^2$ tells me that $a=0$, but where do I go from here? Does this mean that $b$ and $c$ are free variables and the dimension is $2$? Does running through examples $(a, ax, a+bx, a+bx+cx^2, bx+cx^2)$ prove that $b$ and $c$ are free? If they are free, what does the basis look like?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2222616/265466, which already has pretty much the same answer for part (b).

Comment: Do. Not. Reask. EVER!  Also, it looks like reading [this help center page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) might help you with your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the integral equation as
$$
\int_{-2}^0 p(x) \,\mathrm{d}x - 4\cdot \int_0^2 p(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0 \tag{$\ast$}.
$$
Now you can define a linear functional, i.e. some $\varphi \in P_2'$ as 
$$
\varphi(p) := \int_{-2}^0 p(x) \,\mathrm{d}x - 4\cdot \int_0^2 p(x) \,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
That $\varphi$ is indeed linear follows from the linearity of the integral. So basically you have to determine $\ker \varphi$. For this you should rewrite $(\ast)$ for a general element $p = cx^2 + bx + a$ of $P_2$. This gives you 
$$
\left[ \frac{c}{3}x^3 + \frac{b}{2}x^2 + ax\right]_{-2}^0 - 4\cdot \left[ \frac{c}{3}x^3 + \frac{b}{2}x^2 + ax\right]_{0}^2\\
= \frac{c}{3}  (8 - 4 \cdot 8) + \frac{b}{2} (-4 -4 \cdot 4) + a(2 - 4 \cdot 2) \\
= \frac{-24 c}{3} + \frac{-20 b}{2} + (-6)a = -8c - 10b - 6a \overset{!}{=}0
$$
Now $8c + 10b + 6a = 0$ is a linear system of equations. Do you know how to proceed from here?

Comment: Does this mean that I can choose a to be 0 and b and c are free, therefore the dimension is 2 and a spanning set would be something like {(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}?

Comment: @John: Yes, the dimension of the kernel is 2 (this will also follow from the rank-nullity theorem - note that $\varphi \colon P_2 \to \mathbb R$. I don't know why you want to choose $a = 0$.

Comment: If the dimension of the kernel in this case is 2, then dim(W) is 2 right? And how would I write a basis for 6a+8c+10b=0? How do I know which variables are free?

Comment: @John There is no basis for $6a + 8c + 10b = 0$. Only (sub-)vector spaces have bases, not linear equations.

Comment: So how do I find a basis for W as the question asks? And is dim(w)=2?

Comment: @John: Maybe, this would be a good time to look up how to determine the null space of a set of linear equations, since this seems to be the only remaining problem. I'm confident that you will find something suitable by querying a search engine of you liking.

Comment: Computing (6  10  8)(a, b, c)= (0) tells me that a=(-5/3)b-(4/3)c, so wouldn't the basis then be {(-5/3,1,0),(-4/3,0,1)}? And therefore the dimension of W is 2?

Comment: @John: You should be able to verify this by yourself: Are the vectors you found in $W$? Are they linearly independent? Then, you have found a basis, since $\dim W = 2$ by the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: @John Note also that your basis has to consist of polynomials $p = ax^2 + bx + c$, i.e. if $(1,2,3)$ is a solution to the linear equation, then $p = 3x^2 + 2x + 1$ is an element of $W$.